# Spring logging configuration with custom properties

Tags: java, spring, logging, properties

I have to configure logging for a Spring Boot application, but I don't know how I could use custom properties and JVM options in logback-spring.xml.

Let's say I have the following properties:

- application.properties: logging.app.name=app
- JVM options: -Dlogging.app.version=1.0
- (additionally I need active profile and hostname)

Then the filename and log entry should be the following:

- app-[HOSTNAME].log
- 2017/08/25 01:02:03.456 INFO app/1.0/[PROFILE] [main] Some log...

As I know I cannot simply access to these properties in my logging configuration (spring-logback.xml). That's why I tried to create these beans (ConsoleAppender, RollingFileAppender) manually in a configuration class, but it didn't work for me. I also tried implementing the afterPropertiesSet method of InitializingBean and put these variables manually for Logback, but this didn't help either and I start running out of ideas. So any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps this might help? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Comment: I already read this documentation, but it doesn't say anything about how to access custom properties. :(

Comment: Did this not help for setting the file name at least? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#_environment_properties

Comment: Hostname should come from an environment variable, I don't want to write into application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run app with this configurations where you can define the path to `application.properties` and also provide the `logback` configuration file.

```
$java -jar /{pathToJar}/myApp.jar 
--spring.config.location=/{pathToFolderWithCustomeProperties}/application.properties 
--logging.config=/{path}/logback.xml 
-Dlogback.configurationFile=/{path}/logback.xml
```